# ERROR: Kendo"Something" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, xslt, kendo-ui

So I am trying to convert my plain HTML/Javascript site (which works fine) into an ASP MVC4 project. What I do is get and XML and use and XSLT to transform. I litreally use the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471391/using-xslt-in-asp-net-mvc-3) to do that

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I use razor to load the resource

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        
 ... things...
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendoScripts")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customScript") 
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/Kendo")
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/customCSS")
```

my view that uses the layout is very straight forward, this is all that is in the page

```
@using Summ.ExtensionCode
@model SumMVC.Models.SummaryModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "_Summary";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div data-role="content">
@Html.RenderXml(Model.ProgramFilename, Model.StylesheetFilename, Model.Parameters)
</div>
```

In `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customScript")`, is a JS file, renderpage.js that has this bit of code `$(this).kendoDropDownList();` where this is a select element. But I am getting a error that `.kendoDropDownList();` is not a function. The error from firebug: `TypeError: $(...).kendoDropDownList is not a function` and the errror from GoogleChrome `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoDropDownList'`. It seems that in my bundle the JS file kendo.all.min.js is not begin loaded here is what is looks like

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendoScripts")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendoui/kendo.web.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendoui/kendo.all.min.js")
            );

....
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customScript")
           .....
            .Include("~/Scripts/SummaryScript/renderpage.js")
             ....                       
            );
```

I am assuming that perhaps the code is being executed before kendo.all.min.js is done loading, but as you can see above renderpage.js is after kendo. Any ideas or insight?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add that when I manually load the resource in the MVC project in the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/kendoui/kendo.web.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/kendoui/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ExecSummaryScript/renderpage.js"></script>
```

it works fine.

**Update2**

Turns out the Kendo JS file is not being loaded at all. I check the resource in the dev console and notice that it not even there.Upon closer inspection I notice that all resources are loaded except some `.min.js` files. There are a few loaded but some that are not loaded are jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js, and jquery.browser.min.js.

Comment: This means the jquery plugin "kendoDropDownList" is not included, or was included on a different version of jquery than what is currently represented by `$`

Comment: @KevinB That's what I though too. So what I did was replace jquery 1.8 with 1.9 no luck there, and also tries jqueryMigrate from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ nothing there too. I should note that I included everything from the HTML/Javascript project and it all works fine just not in the MVC project

Comment: the version of jquery is irrelevant, what's important is where jquery is included on the page relative to kendoui

Comment: @KevinB Yeah seems that the Kendoui comes package with jquery. As said in the answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382884/issues-with-kendoui-and-jquery-1-9-0 Also I do see a jquery.min.js inside the kendoui folder that I got.

Comment: @KevinB Upon closer inspection I notice that all resources are loaded except some `.min.js` files. There are a few loaded but some that are not loaded are jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js, and jquery.browser.min.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew it was going to be something stupid. Turns out that it's a MVC4 gothcha. I had to rename my file. Appearently it did not like files with extension `min.js`  [I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files)