# XSLT, XML. HTML helper not working

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

So I retrieve an XML and XSLT as strings from the DB then used my custom HTML helper called `RenderXml` to render. The problem is that it is not rendering properly. In my  HTML helper is where I do the transformation

```
public static HtmlString RenderXml(this HtmlHelper helper, string theXml, string theXslt)
 {          
  XDocument xmlTree = XDocument.Parse(xmlPath);          
  XDocument newTree = new XDocument();
  using (XmlWriter writer = newTree.CreateWriter())
  {
    // Load the style sheet.
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltPath)));
    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
    xslt.Transform(xmlTree.CreateReader(), writer);
    return new HtmlString(newTree.ToString());
   }            
  }
```

in my CSHTML I do it like this

```
<div id="results">@Html.RenderXml(Model.theXmlFile, Model.theXSLFile,)</div>
```

When I try to return `new HtmlString(newTree.ToString());` I get a blank, and when I try to return `new HtmlString(writer.ToString());` I get this `System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter` on the page. Do anybody know what I am doing wrong? I got my code from [the example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675186.aspx). I have also looked into [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471391/using-xslt-in-asp-net-mvc-3) and it works great except I do not use a URI, and when I try to modify it to use XDocument complains about missing parameters, so I stayed away from it. Any ideas why he transformation is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the line `return new HtmlString(newTree.ToString());` outside of the `using` block:

```
  using (XmlWriter writer = newTree.CreateWriter())
  {
    // Load the style sheet.
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltPath)));
    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
    xslt.Transform(xmlTree.CreateReader(), writer);
  }
  return new HtmlString(newTree.ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry took me awhile to accept the answer. It just really? really? OMG :)