# Create HTML Table with XML in a asp.net MVC C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I've planned a new Application.
My Idea is, to generate XML docs. I need a way to convert this XML docs to a HTML Table.

My XML structure is:

```
<Checklist>
  <Title>Titletext</Title>
     <Group>
       <Title>Active Directory</Title>
       <Content>
        <Line>
          <text type="array">
            <value>Connect to:</value>
            <value>dsa.msc start</value>
          </text>
         </Line>
         <Line>
          <text type="array">
            <value>Gruppen anpassen anhand des Arbeitsortes</value>
            <value>Profilpfad eintragen</value>
          </text>
         </Line>
       </Content>
     </Group>
   </Checklist>
```

I'll try to convert this xml to HTML Tables like this:

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr class="head">
      <td>#Group -> Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text">
      <td><p>#Line -> Value 1</p><p>@Line -> Value2</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

My first idea was, to read the XML line by line, and add this values to a ListArray.
With a foreach i'll try to generate the HTML

```
foreach(string item in ViewBag.Content)
```

Is there a much "better" option or should i try to solve this this way =)
Maybe someone can give me a best practice hint or something =)

Thanks!

Comment: use xpath or xlst tranformation.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use Extensible Stylesheet Language ([XSL](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_languages.asp)). You can use XSL Tansformations ([XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_intro.asp)) to create templates in xml which sets out rules on how to convert XML into another format. In your case the template would be something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="Checklist/Title/Group/Title" /></th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Checklist/Group/Content/Line">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Value">
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="value" /></p> 
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
       </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's a good example on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778299/simplest-way-to-transform-xml-to-html-with-xslt-in-c) shows you how to implement it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard way of doing this:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471391/using-xslt-in-asp-net-mvc-3) for MVC integration

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd create a class that represents a row of your table - a model.

Than I would use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb387098%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the xml file to a list of objects of your model class.

Than, instead of putting it to the ViewBag, I'd put the list of model objects as a View's model (it can be strongly typed). In the controller you return the view this way:

```
List<MyModel> items = ....
return View(items)
```

And finally I'd iterate through it in Razor like that:

```
@foreach(var item in Model){ // the Model here is whatever you passed to the View method call in your controller
   // create table rows or whatever you need
}
```