# Can you add a response CacheDependency with a relative file path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xslt, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently writing an MVC 5 application and one of my web pages requires that I transform some XML using an XSLT and render the results as HTML on a web page, I've managed to get this working using this great example here: [Using XSLT in ASP .NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471391/using-xslt-in-asp-net-mvc-3).

This example appears to add a CacheDependency to the Response object, however the constructor for a new CacheDependency requires you pass an absolute file path to the XSLT. This is working fine if I pass the hard disk location of the XSLT to the constructor for eg:

```
Response.AddCacheDependency(new CacheDependency(@"C:\Mytempalates\TheTemplate.xslt"));
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible pass a virtual/relative path as a parameter to this constructor instead as Ideally I don't want to be hitting the disk.

So if my template was hosted at: http://www.mywebsite.com/Templates/TheTemplate.xslt
How can I add it as a CacheDependency?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was wrong: A custom cache dependency class can only monitor local files and not URL files.

The alternative is to create a timer that checks the URL's content using an interval, and if it notices a change, then you manually invalidate the cache by setting Cache["URLContent"] = null.

Let me know if you need help understanding this.

Comment: If I'm creating a custom cache dependency do I need to inherit from CacheDependency at all?

Comment: For a custom one yes.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. Is it necessary that I add a CacheDependency at all? Going on your answer, what properties of the CacheDepency class would I utilise by inheriting?